# Multiple rows * rows

Tags: r, dplyr, reshape

i have a sample data set as below

```
variable=c("i","x1","x2","x3","v1","v2","v3","g1","g2","g3")
df=data.frame(replicate(10,sample(0:100,10,rep=TRUE)))
df$var=variable
df
  X1 X2 X3  X4 X5 X6  X7 X8 X9 X10 var
1  48  0 65  16 40 85  43 74 25  17   i
2  29 74 19  11 34 65  94 72 10  75  x1
3  21 66 78   4 76 86  85 59 17  27  x2
4  19 87 55 100 51 38  33 63 94  10  x3
5  67 37 86  69 50 90  98 22 18  46  v1
6  67 47 28  82 96 66 100 57 99  47  v2
7  82  5 38  27 14 87  36  9  9  86  v3
8  66  6 18  43 24 96  94 95 79   0  g1
9  52 79 69  82 89 58  46 28 30   8  g2
10  0 49 24  16 79 86  53 86 23  51  g3
```

Here the column var is key. What i want to do is generate a table where each row presents combinations of i,Xs,Vs,Gs. for example one row would be

```
var_comb            X1      X2  .................X10              
"i,x1,v1,g1"       6155424
"i,x1,v1,g2"       4849728
```

the X1 value there is (48*29*67*66) i.e values from original table similary second combination is (48*29*67*52)

Like that there are 3*3*3 = 27 rows of combinations. How i generate the desired output?

Note x,v and g are like different variables with 1,2,3 being their levels. They don't have to be multiplied among each other( i.e. combination like "i,x1,x2,v1") but with each other - each unique level of x with unique level of v and g)

Comment: Where is the info about the row combinations?  Also, note that there is no 'i' column

Comment: it is a multiplication of the all the numbers( their corresponding values in each column X1,X2...X10) the orignal table i.e. for combination x1,v1,g1 and i(which doesnt have any levels)

Comment: Since you used `sample(0:100,10,rep=TRUE)`, we cannot see where `48*29*67*66` come from. Please use `set.seed`.

Comment: output table would have 10 columns ( same as X1,X2....X10) and have 27 rows which are the combinations of the var variables)

Comment: May be something like `combn(df$var, 4, FUN = function(nm) matrixStats::rowProds(as.matrix(df[match(nm, df$var), setdiff(names(df), 'var')])))`

Comment: are you saying that the first row with 'i' should be common in all multiplications

Comment: yes, "i" should be common. your earlier output gives 4 rows with 210 columns, doesn't seem to be working

Comment: Note that 27 combinations are based on 'x', 'v' and 'g' .  It doesn't differentiate the levels of each 'x's or 'v's to use in that combination for multiplying.  If the selection is random, it makes sense

Comment: Each new level is a combination of individual levels of Xs, Ys, Zs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution with `data.table`:

```
library("data.table")
D <- fread(
"  X1 X2 X3  X4 X5 X6  X7 X8 X9 X10 var
48  0 65  16 40 85  43 74 25  17   i
29 74 19  11 34 65  94 72 10  75  x1
21 66 78   4 76 86  85 59 17  27  x2
19 87 55 100 51 38  33 63 94  10  x3
67 37 86  69 50 90  98 22 18  46  v1
67 47 28  82 96 66 100 57 99  47  v2
82  5 38  27 14 87  36  9  9  86  v3
66  6 18  43 24 96  94 95 79   0  g1
52 79 69  82 89 58  46 28 30   8  g2
0 49 24  16 79 86  53 86 23  51  g3"
)

var_comb <- c("i,x1,v1,g1", "i,x1,v1,g2")

L <- strsplit(var_comb, ",")

myfun <- function(Rows) {
  sapply(D[var %in% Rows, -11], prod)
}
sapply(L, myfun)
data.table(var_comb, t(sapply(L, myfun)))
```

The function `myfun()` takes a character vector of the rowindicators. `D[var %in% Rows, -11]` selects the rows using a logical index vector and neglects the 11th column. The `sapply(..., prod)` calculates the product for each column.
To generate all combinations for `var_comb`do:

```
expand.grid("i", paste0("x", 1:3), paste0("v", 1:3), paste0("g", 1:3))
```

So you can put it together:

```
Var_Comb <- expand.grid("i", paste0("x", 1:3), paste0("v", 1:3), paste0("g", 1:3))
apply(Var_Comb, 1, myfun)
var_comb <- apply(Var_Comb, 1, paste0, collapse=',')
data.table(var_comb, t(apply(Var_Comb, 1, myfun)))
```

#### for base R:

```
setDF(D)  ## only needed for using the data.table D from above

var_comb <- c("i,x1,v1,g1", "i,x1,v1,g2")

L <- strsplit(var_comb, ",")

myfun <- function(Rows) {
  sapply(D[D$var %in% Rows, -11], prod)
}
sapply(L, myfun)
data.frame(var_comb, t(sapply(L, myfun)))
```

and (the same as in the data.table-variant):

```
Var_Comb <- expand.grid("i", paste0("x", 1:3), paste0("v", 1:3), paste0("g", 1:3))
apply(Var_Comb, 1, myfun)
var_comb <- apply(Var_Comb, 1, paste0, collapse=',')
data.table(var_comb, t(apply(Var_Comb, 1, myfun)))
```

Comment: yes it does work but can you comment on the function myfun

Comment: how does it create the logical index vector that you mentioned above

Comment: The logical index is the result of `D$var %in% Rows` Please read the documentation of `%in%`

Comment: which component explains the part where it knows not to multiply x1 with x2 or x1 with x3?

Comment: `expand.grid("i", paste0("x", 1:3), paste0("v", 1:3), paste0("g", 1:3))` - have a look on the result (and the documentation of `expand()`).